# server back button is working after logout in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In my website when I log-out from admin panel but the back button of server is working when I click on back button of server (chrome)  then it is logged in.

How to  disable the session and cookies?

Comment: To make a good question you need to at least tell us what you have tried. You may also want to post relevant bits of your code along with that, like the code that handles logging out.

Answer (score 0):

Try with abandon() function,

```
 Session.Abandon();
```

Use the above line on your logout button click event.

Comment: Then show your logout button click event with source page. If you used this, sure you won't get to previous page. Because, it will clear all the session and caches which are stored in client side.

Answer (score 0):

Back button works because browser doesn't send a request to server when user clicks back it just retrieves a cached copy of previous page and shows it to the user.

You must have noticed that as soon as you click any link or button on the page that is displayed after back click of browser it should have thrown you back to the login page. If this is not happening then you are not abandoning your session on logout, Use `Session.Abandon()` for that.

However there's a trick of doing that using below mentioned steps:

1. Create a page signout.aspx or something like that.
2. When user clicks on Logout redirect him to that signout.aspx first.
3. Clear all session on `page_load` of signout.aspx and on Javascript side of this page redirect user to `Login.aspx` on load of document you can user `document.ready` of Jquery for this.

Now when user will click back he'll be redirected to signout.aspx and due to that Javascript/Jaquery he'll be redirected back to Login.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code on your login page

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```